# Website for playing Cylinder Chess

Tags: chess-variants

Does anybody know a website where I can play [Cylinder Chess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder_chess)? I'm looking for something similar to [Chess.com](http://www.chess.com/) but for Cylinder.

Comment: The wiki page you posted has a [link](http://brainking.com/) to such a website.

Comment: Yes, but you cannot play live games, only correspondence games on that site.

Comment: I don't know a site for playing live against humans, but you can play cylinder chess against the variants engine [Fairy-Max](http://home.hccnet.nl/h.g.muller/CVfairy.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who are still looking for somewhere to easily play cylinder chess online (live), you can now do so on [cylinderchess.com](https://www.cylinderchess.com). I'm a student and put this web app together in my spare time. It's entirely free to use (+ no plugins needed and no ads). Gameplay is on an animated 3D cylinder or you can choose to play on a square board (pieces still wrap around the board).

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with this variant, but as most variants, [pathguy has it.](http://www.pathguy.com/chess/Cylinder.htm) You can also play in http://brainking.com/ correspondence and using http://home.hccnet.nl/h.g.muller/CVfairy.html to play against an engine.

Also I cannot confirm it, but ICC has lots of chess variants. You might want to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

If i remember correctly, you can play this variant on `www.buho21.com`.
The only problem is that nearly everything is written in spanish there.